# Unable to locate the .NET SDK as specified by global.json, please check that the specified version is installed

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, f#

trying to start a .NET console application. Would prefer F# but get the same error in C# or VB as well.

`Unable to locate the .NET SDK as specified by global.json, please check that the specified version is installed`. I get that warning as soon as I create a new application, and get it as an error when I try to build.

This is using the default Hello World templates that come with Visual Studio. I would expect the prebuilt templates that ship with the app to build first time. Using VS 2019 16.8.5.

I have searched Visual Studio project and the source directory and can't find any global.json.

[image: The errors]

EDIT: Found the global.json at C:\users\username

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "3.1.300",
    "rollForward": "latestMinor"
  }
}
```

Which I'm fairly sure I have the SDK installed for but will double check.

Comment: You can get a list of all installed SDKs by running `dotnet --list-sdks`

Comment: When you create a project, are you targeting .NET Framework or .NET Core? Given that version number, I suspect .NET Core. Was that the intention?

Comment: .NET core was the intention. I was getting different errors on standard .NET. Changing the rollForward to "latestMajor" seems to have worked.

Comment: Sorry but I think all answers are not ok for your problem: You need to specify your minimun (and installed) needed version i.e. "version": "6.0.100" in the global.json and then add "rollForward": "latestMajor" in order to use any upper installed version (the most up to date one) automatically, otherwise it will be awful to scale/update your project, with this solution you can always run your project with ANY version >= 6.0.100

Answer (score 32):

In my case my global.json was referring to an SDK I didn't have.  Run the below in your terminal

```
dotnet --list-sdks
```

That will give you the list of all the SDK's available, here you can either update your global.json file to the version you have (or install the missing SDK if you need to)

Comment: running above command helped me to get the available sdks, available was 3.1.403 and required was 3.1.412, so to make it work, i changed the global.json file and build the solution. it worked like charm.

Comment: It's not a valid solution for production purposes since you need to install a determinate version and can't update it, you need to specify the minimun needed version i.e. "version": "6.0.100" in the global.json and then add "rollForward": "latestMajor" in order to use any upper installed version (the most up to date one) automatically, otherwise it will be awful to scale your project

Comment: A thing I stumbled on was _how_ exactly to install the correct SDK, there seem to be a few ways to do this. I ended up using the command described on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/windows?tabs=net80#install-with-windows-package-manager-winget) - `winget install Microsoft.DotNet.Runtime.6` (I was missing the .NET 6.0 SDK)

Answer (score 6):

I would advise removing that `global.json` file instead of just adding `latestMajor` to it, since it's in a place where it probably shouldn't be. Having one in the root of `C:\users\your-name` with that value is functionally equivalent to not having it in the first place.

The general purpose of a `global.json` file is to lock down the SDK version used *for a specific codebase*. For example, this can be helpful if you're using a CI system that can install a .NET SDK based on a `global.json` file, so you don't have multiple places to update your toolset over time.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed this problem after discovering a global.json file at the directory root of a C# solution. This json file specified a specific sub version of .Net 7, after deleting the solution-level global.json the build error was solved.

Additional Info: This problem occurred for me after cloning a GitHub repository on my local PC. The C# repository contained two solutions and the problem global.json file was declared at the common directory root of the two solutions but it was not visible in the VS2022 solution explorer.

Comment: Delete the global.json at the root of your solution and this works.

Answer (score 3):

Check rollForward is disabled or not
If disabled the make it latestMinor

**"rollForward": "latestMinor"**

Comment: What he really need is to have a minimum version specified on global.json i.e "version": "6.0.100", and then add "rollForward": "latestMajor" in order to use any upper installed version (the most up to date one) automatically, otherwise it will be awful to scale/update his project

Answer (score 1):

I have downloaded sdk version and after restart VS all work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Same. One thing extra I did was set my Global.json to the version I downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues my error was ...

> warning : The NuGetSdkResolver did not resolve this SDK because there was no version specified in the project or global.json.

I was trying to build my app using the cli

```
dotnet build
```

So I found others talking about similar issues on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/2532) Which made it seem like a *Path issue*, so I looked on the Microsoft Docs for checking dotnet versions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/how-to-detect-installed-versions?pivots=os-windows#check-sdk-versions)

**Check for install folders**

It's possible that .NET is installed but not added to the PATH variable for your operating system or user profile. In this case, the commands from the previous sections may not work. As an alternative, you can check that the .NET install folders exist.

When you install .NET from an installer or script, it's installed to a standard folder. Much of the time the installer or script you're using to install .NET gives you an option to install to a different folder. If you choose to install to a different folder, adjust the start of the folder path.

---

```
dotnet executable
C:\program files\dotnet\dotnet.exe

.NET SDK
C:\program files\dotnet\sdk\{version}\

.NET Runtime
C:\program files\dotnet\shared\{runtime-type}\{version}\
```

##### So I added when paths to Enviroment Variables like so...

- I am running .NET6 mainly as of right now

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.405\
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe
C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.13\
C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App\6.0.13\
C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.13\
```

[image: My Enviroment Variables]

##### And now it is working for me

[image: Running dotnet build in powershell]

Answer (score 0):

First run cmd
and enter this command:
dotnet --version

[image]

then edit your global.json file according that

Answer (score 0):

Change the sdk version as installed. You can find by running the command in terminal in VSC or "Developer Powershell" in VS.
Then change the version to the version you want.
Like in my case 6.0.408 was there annd I changed it to 6.0.128.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/how-to-detect-installed-versions?pivots=os-windows